# How to read chrome extension development documentation?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Looks like the documentation is stable. But I am a bit frustrated about its conventions. For example, what is the field **name** in the following screenshot? Any one help point where the guideline for reading the documentation is? [image: sample]

Comment: The documentation assumes familiarity with JavaScript. The connectInfo "object," for example, is what other languages like Python might call a dictionary, or that languages like Ruby might call a hash. So within that object/dictionary/hash is one key-value pair whose name is "name" and type is string. Perhaps if you're more familiar with a non-JavaScript language, reading "object" as "dictionary" or "hash" makes the rest of the screenshot clear. If that doesn't help, the Chrome sample code generally covers each API at least once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`name` in this case is an optional name you can use for the port. You use it like this:

```
var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name:"testName"});
```

After that, `port.name` would be `"testName"`.

`connectInfo` is defined to be an object meaning that any field listed indented under it, like `name` is, is a part of it.

Comment: Thanks. I eventually got it. 'name' is a field of the argument object 'connectInfo'，but not another argument of the function 'connect'. The function 'connect' smartly uses the arguments supplied as one is 'string', the other is 'object'.